# I have 2 bodies in swift that when collide I want to bounceoff of each other, How can I make this possible so it won't sense the collision?

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, physics, collision

I have a roof Sprite Node that i would like for the Player Sprite Node to bounce off of, but when they touch it runs my collision function.
Roof and player physics category:

```
struct PhysicsCatagory {
static let Player : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
static let Roof : UInt32 = 0x1 << 6
```

}

Player and Roof code:

```
   Player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plane")
    Player.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 70)
    Player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Player.size)
    Player.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 - Player.frame.width, y: self.frame.width / 2)
    Player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Player
    Player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ground | PhysicsCatagory.Mine | PhysicsCatagory.Ep | PhysicsCatagory.Bullet
    Player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ground | PhysicsCatagory.Mine | PhysicsCatagory.Ep | PhysicsCatagory.Bullet
    Player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Player.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Player.zPosition = 4

   Roof.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: 40)
    Roof.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Roof.size)
    Roof.position = CGPoint(x:  self.frame.width / 2, y:  self.frame.height - 20)
    Roof.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Roof
    Roof.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Roof.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Roof.zPosition = 4
```

And here is my code for when a collision occurs:

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    game = false
    end = true
    soundy = false
    self.removeAllChildren()
    self.removeAllActions()
    endScreen()

}
```

I have tried changing their identities to 0 but then the player just goes through the roof. If you know anything about this please leave any recommendations or suggestions below. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

remove `contactTestBitmask` if you dont want didBeginContact to occur

Comment: I want contact to occur, just not between the payer and the roof.